# SQLite - Importing .csv data to database every day

Tags: sqlite, csv, batch-file, cmd, import

So I need to import some .csv file every day in our firm. My idea was to write a .bat file and run it everyday automatically through Task Scheduler. The problem is that i can't succeed at writting .bat file correctly. It's working when I type physically in CMD (sqlite3) but don't do anything when I transform it to .bat file and run it.

CMD:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sqlite3.exe
SQLite version 3.34.0 2020-12-01 16:14:00
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> ATTACH DATABASE "C:\...\database.db" AS "name";
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .separator ;
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> .import "\\\\path\\..." "dbname"
sqlite> SELECT * from "dbname"
```

The result is the way I want, so all the data is in the database correctly.

Do anyone has an idea how to transform this to a .bat file?

Comment: Did you try to put your sqlite commands into an .sql file and use it with input redirection?

Comment: What does your .bat file look like?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield pretty much the same as the CMD.

Comment: @Compo yes,i have tried, it's more complicated way.

Comment: Well I don't believe it is more complicated at all, and it is how I believe you should be doing it. The way you are attempting it, is not correct, and will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a solution that works! I created a .bat file with the next code:

```
 @ECHO off
 sqlite3.exe -cmd ".mode csv" -cmd ".separator ";"" -cmd ".import C:\\the path to the .csv file\\ myTable" C:\the path to the database
 pause
```

and it works with the task scheduler.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

- Create a text file for the sqlite script
- The batch file will be something like `sqlite3 ":memory:" ".read sqlite.script"`

Et voilà! The first argument to sqlite3 is the database name, the following arguments are CLI "executables".